# Composer Chaincode containers lifecycle

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger fabric each chaincode deployed runs in a separate docker container.

Hyperledger-composer, therefore, creates **a new container at each upgrade** of the chaincode. From my understanding composer-rest-server or any other way to interact with the composer channel **always relies on the last version** that has been deployed.

The framework itself does not stop containers running old chaincodes.

Should I do it manually? Is there a good reason to keep them running?

Comment: I tried to do kill all old containers and then run a complete e2e test suite and everything seems to work smoothly. My question is aimed at a theoretical understanding of the risks involved in the process (if any)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057902/upgrading-hyperledger-fabric-business-network/51063290#51063290 for answer - you can stop them, yes. Suggest to read the link for more detail

Comment: Thank you. If you post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [Upgrading Hyperledger Fabric Business Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057902/upgrading-hyperledger-fabric-business-network/51063290#51063290) for the answer - you can stop them, yes. I suggest to read the link for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Once an information is written on the Blockchain (via Hyperledger Composer or any other mean), you cannot remove it from the ledger.

Keeping the containers running old chaincodes can be considered as a mean to recover your network (for example, if you made a mistake in the ACL and you cannot access to your network anymore).

You can kill and remove old Docker containers using the following commands:

```
docker kill ID_OF_THE_OLD_CONTAINER

docker rm ID_OF_THE_OLD_CONTAINER
```